# Sql view with column identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am creating a select query with union of three tables....
like this

```
select a as A,b as B c as C where c = x union
select b as A,d as B e as C where e = y and d = a union
select f as A,g as B,h as C
```

and the result of query is like this:

```
A   B   C
===========
1   abc ...
55  def ...
1   sas ...
```

so I want to have a column that count the number of row, just to prevent the repetition of identifier.
Somthing like this

```
Row  A   B   C
================
1    1   abc ...
2    55  def ...
3    1   sas ...
```

....

My question is how it can be done?

Comment: Look at `ROW_NUMBER()` in 2008

Comment: I try that but i haven't seen it working on a union

Comment: Do you care about what order you get the rows in? Do you care if "Row" is an integer, starting from 1 and running up to the number of rows? If not, there's also `NEWID()`, which may be easier to use here.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Vega Neira: ROW_NUMBER() will work if you use derived table or CTE. For example, `SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...) FROM (your query with union)a`

Comment: Put the union in a CTE or a subquery, then apply Row_number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vname
AS
    SELECT [Row] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A), A, B, C FROM
    ( <UNION query here> ) AS x;
```

Replace ORDER BY A with whatever ordering you'd like to see applied. Note that you will need to use ORDER BY on the outer query against dbo.viewname to guarantee that Row will come out in that order.

Answer (score 5):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A,B,C) AS RowNo, *
FROM
(
select a as A,b as B c as C where c = x 
union
select b as A,d as B e as C where e = y and d = a 
union
select f as A,g as B,h as C
) x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common table expression to achieve this:

```
WITH unionTable
AS
(
    select a as A, b as B, c as C where c = x union
    select b as A, d as B, e as C where e = y and d = a union
    select f as A, g as B, h as C
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A) AS RowNumber, * 
FROM unionTable
```